# Data written to disk callback

Tags: c++, linux, unix

How can I get callbacks once data has been **successfully** written to disk in Linux?

I would like to have my programs db file mapped into memory for read/write operations and receive callbacks once a write has successfully hit disk. Kind of like what the old VMSs used to do..

Comment: Can you provide more details on what you have already tried and what parts of the code you are having trouble with?  In its current form, this question may get a simple "yes" or "no" answer.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet. I'm looking for a way in program to confirm that data has actually been committed to disk. I've looked into DBMS journaling techniques but I'd like to avoid that path if possible... Would prefer a signal from the OS saying I've finished writing this chunk to disk. Is there such a thing?

Comment: You may need to use journalling anyway - between when you issue the write and when the sync finishes, any data blocks being written to (even partially) may be completely lost if the system loses power at that moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call fdatasync (or fsync if you really need the metadata to be synchronised as well) and wait for it to return.

You could do this from another thread, but if one thread writes to the file while another thread is doing a fdatasync(), it's not going to be clear which of the writes are guaranteed to be persistent or not.

Databases which want to store transaction logs in a guaranteed-durable way, need to call fdatasync.

Databases (such as innodb) typically use direct IO (as well as their own data-caching, rather than rely on the OS) on their main data files, so that they know that it will be written in a predictable manner.

Comment: This is correct.  If you want a callback, simply use a thread which does the write, calls `fdatasync()` / `msync()` or similar, then calls your callback.

Comment: I'm not sure how "simply" really applies to this. Having a thread doing the callback may not be what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you cannot get any notification when the actual synchronization between a file (or a `mmap`ed region) happen, not even the timestamps of the file are going to change. You can, however, force the synchronization of the file (or region) by using `fsync`.

It is also hard to see a reason for why you would want that. File IO is supposed to be opaque.

Comment: mmh.. I can see plenty of reasons.

Comment: The reason I need it, is that I need to generate customer receipts once the write to disk has been absolutely confirmed. Can not afford the chance that a receipt is out in the open for a piece of data that failed to write to disk..

Comment: @gamedynamix I'd suggest you just do your write and call `fsync` that way you can be sure that the data is written and generate your receipt.